# Equality between Möbius transformations at the same argument

Tags: complex-numbers, mobius-transformation

Let $f(z)=(az+b)/(cz+d)$ and $g(z)=az/(ez+f)$ be two Möbius transformations, with $a,b,c,d,e,f$ real numbers (note the same coefficient $a$ in $f$ and $g$) and with $cz+d$ and $ez+f$ non constant.

My question is: What conditions we can deduce about the coefficients of $f$ and $g$, if $f(\omega)=g(\omega)$, for some non-real number $\omega$?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can just write out what $f(\omega)=g(\omega)$ means: $$\frac{a\omega+b}{c\omega+d}=\frac{a\omega}{e\omega+f}.$$  Cross-multiplying and simplifying gives $$a(e-c)\omega^2+(be+a(f-d))\omega+bf=0.$$  If the leading coefficient $a(e-c)$ is nonzero, this is a quadratic with real coefficients, so it has a nonreal root iff the discriminant $$(be+a(f-d))^2-4abf(e-c)$$ is negative.

If $a(e-c)=0$ then the only way there can be a nonreal root is if all the coefficients are $0$.  This just means that $f(z)=g(z)$ for all $z$, so they have the same coefficients up to scaling and hence the same coefficients since they have a common nonzero coefficient of $a$.  (Note that if you actually try to solve for when $a(e-c)=be+a(f-d)=bf=0$, you will find some other solutions such as $a=b=0$, but those are all degenerate and would make the original functions not actually be Möbius transformations.)

Answer (score 0):

You have two functions which take the same value at one point, where this point has non-trivial imaginary part (if I understand you correctly). This might impose some restriction on $a,b,c,d,e,f$, for example you can express $f$ as a function of your other five constants, but that's probably it.